# Is surjectivity superfluous for the definition of valuation?

Tags: commutative-algebra, definition

> Let $F$ be a field and $\Gamma$ be an ordered abelian group and $v:F^*\rightarrow \Gamma$ be a function satisfying the following:
>
> 1. $v(xy)=v(x)+v(y)$
> 2. $v(x+y)\geq \min\{v(x),v(y)\}$ if $x+y\neq 0$
>
> Then, we say **$(v,\Gamma)$ is a valuation of $F$**.

Some authors require $v$ to be surjective in addition, but some do not. Is the surjectivity condition for $v$ superfluous? If not, what is the standard definition for valuation of a field?

Comment: No surjectivity is not superfluous. What you wrote is the standard definition of valuation. The reason why some authors demand surjectivity is simply because all the valuations they care about in practice is surjective.

Comment: For the above definition, $\Gamma$ plays no role, only the image of $\nu$ does and so replacing $\Gamma$ with the image, you can always assume surjectivity.